# data collection & views

Tags: forms

I have created a website for neighborhood on d7 for a society of 400 apartments. We need to collect data from each user (like is he a tenant or a owner, his profession, his car registration no, members in the family with age, and respective ID cards to verify and arrange facilities membership card, carparking,maid  access etc. I had accomplished this questionre by using webform,and only later I understand that this is more meant for survey one way. I cannot again use this data and give user a option of edit. example if the user changes his car / maid he should be able to change it online. Data collection from the users have not yet been started.  What would be the best way to collect this type of data and later be used in views, this also has conditions /logic based question example if he is a owner he has a different set of questions and if he is a tenant then different set. Around 3-4 logic questions are involved.

I don't know php. But love drupal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to give each user an account / profile. Then add the fields you need to the user profile and the people can provide all the information you need by themselfs. And they can update the data whenever something changes. Or even you can update the data if they're not able to do it or forget about changing them on your site.

An other way would be to have a content type if you dont want user profiles. But in this case, you have to maintain and update the data.

Comment: Thanks for this guidance.How to add conditions/logic to the questions. Example We have a extra set of fields to be added if the user is a doctor.can this be possible using profile2 module. After we collect the data can we also restrict them from changing certain fields.

Comment: I would not use profile2 because you can do everything on the user profiles because they are fieldable in drupal 7. To add logic or conditions to the profiles you could use Conditional Fields Module or if this isn't enough, write your own module.